# Get api data from another .py file in python flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask

My goal is to get data from one python file `main.py` to another python file `tut.py`. The `main.py` will be like an api that sends data to the route in `tut.py`. I will appreciate any assistance or another possible way. Thanks.

**main.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api, Resource

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class Datas(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {"SignedMessage":"Men"}
api.add_resource(Datas, "/api")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**tut.py**

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
import requests
from flask_restful import Api, Resource


app = Flask(__name__)
BASE = "http://10.100.17.179:5000/" # my localhost 

#route to get the data from main.py
@app.route("/api12", methods = ['GET'])
def home():
    response = requests.get(BASE + "api")
    print(response)
    return response.json()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you have written is correct. Both main.py and tut.py. However, the problem is, you cannot get both the apps running simultaneously on your local server. So, when you call the API in main.py from tut.py, main.py is not running.
You may check that by including both the code into a single file, say main.py, and running it. It will work. Code for your reference:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
import requests
from flask_restful import Api, Resource


app = Flask(__name__)
BASE = "http://10.100.17.179:5000/" # my localhost 
api = Api(app)

class Datas(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {"SignedMessage":"Men"}
api.add_resource(Datas, "/api")

#route to get the data from main.py
@app.route("/api12", methods = ['GET'])
def home():
    response = requests.get(BASE + "api")
    print(response)
    return response.json()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Now when you call api12, it will call the api. But both have to be in a single file. Or, you would have to get the other one hosted.
To run a complete flask app, you should read this documentation: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/blueprints/

Another approach to getting data from one file to another is importing. In your case, this is how it will work:

**main.py**

```
def functionx():
    result = {"SignedMessage": "Men"}
    return result
```

In your **tut.py**:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
import requests
from flask_restful import Api, Resource
from main import functionx


app = Flask(__name__)
BASE = "http://10.100.17.179:5000/" # my localhost 

#route to get the data from main.py
@app.route("/api12", methods = ['GET'])
def home():
    response = functionx()
    return response.json()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: I prefer to use flask_restful apis. I am fairly new to flask. Thanks.

Comment: Updated my answer to help you better.